# Better layout for showing 3 tables on a page

Tags: tables, design, wireframe

There is a dashboard page which is managed by admin for monitoring countries, industries and notifications going to end user.

I want to show these 3 tables on single page. I have designed those using wire-framing software but I feel this is not efficient design and can be more better. Can anyone help me out for better and efficient design?

Also there is setting icon against each country and industry which I want to move into the table header. But as you can see there is no space to move that setting icon into table header.
[image]

Comment: Why do you feel having the 3 tables on a single page is inefficient design?   Please provide what your end users will be doing with the information on this Dashboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This design has few problems.

1. Cluttering of data
2. Responsiveness

We should always keep in mind about the ratios in which we are dividing our screen and will the ratio work for every or at least most of the devices?

Here you are displaying 3 tables in a row, that is too much data and all of it in one view. This will probably exhaust the user in 10 minutes.

Now regarding the responsiveness of this design, it contains tables which are one of the most hated elements in web design nowadays because they aren't responsive at all. The only thing which you can do with tables is to stack them one over the other for responsiveness. Hence you will need to choose a design which lets you do that.

**Here is one which I will suggest.**

[image]

Keeping the left side and right side in ratio of 9:3 or 8:4 will work for you, as it will be good for responsiveness and will provide you 2 views.
Here, by view I mean Left and right. This helps user to categorize the information on screen.

User will be like : On left side I have detailed tables and on the right side I have notifications.

Hope this helps you with your query.